# strptime() reads years relative to 1900AD

Tags: c, gnu, strptime

I'm using a function that I've understood is not part of the standard C library. I found information about it here: [21.4.6.1 Interpret string according to given format](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Time-String-Parsing.html#Low_002dLevel-Time-String-Parsing).

It is a very helpful function and does exactly what I need. However, when using it in this very simple way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm timedata;
    strptime("1/1/1", "%d/%m/%Y", &timedata);
    printf("day: %d\nmonth: %d\nyear: %d\n", 
        timedata.tm_mday, timedata.tm_mon, timedata.tm_year);
}
```

strange data is placed in the `struct tm` `timedata`. Output is:

```
day: 1
month: 0
year: -1899
```

Which doesn't make much sense to me. `1/1/1` should result in:

```
day: 1
month: 1
year: 1
```

From what I can see, this behaviour isn't to be expected when reading the GNU manual. For example:

> %Y The year as a decimal number, using the Gregorian calendar.

Last time I checked, the Gregorian calendar didn't start at 1900A.D.

EDIT:

Rewrote code to check return value of function. Same problem persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm timedata;
    if(strptime("1/1/1", "%d/%m/%Y", &timedata))
    {
        printf("day: %d\nmonth: %d\nyear: %d\n", 
            timedata.tm_mday, timedata.tm_mon, timedata.tm_year);
    }else{
        printf("Error");
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
day: 1
month: 0
year: -1899
```

Comment: This is entirely predictable if you read [docs for `struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/): `tm_year int years since 1900` The format stored in `struct tm` vs the format parsed by `strptime()` need not be the same, and indeed are not.

Comment: "Last time I checked, the Gregorian calendar didn't start at 1900A.D." It was not in use in year 1 anyway. ;)

Comment: While you only mentioned the "weird" year, you might notice that the month and day are not consistent. Another WTF detail about `struct tm` is, that month starts at 0 but day of month starts at 1. Crazy stuff this struct...

Comment: @Gerhardh The [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) could be used for such early dates before Gregorian calendar's initial use in 1582.

Comment: @Gerhardh Starting `tm_mon` at zero allows ease of displaying a month by name, which is common.  `puts(month_names_array[timedata.tm_mon]);`.  Such were the early design choices of the standard C library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code works correctly.  `struct tm` does not use the same offsets as OP thought.  [@underscore_d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060653/strptime-reads-years-relative-to-1900ad#comment77094913_45060653)

```
// C11dr §7.27.1 4
int tm_mon; // months since January — [0, 11]
int tm_year; // years since 1900
```

---

```
int main() {
    struct tm timedata;
    char *p = strptime("1/1/1", "%d/%m/%Y", &timedata);
    if (p) {
      printf("day: %d\nmonth since January: %d\nyear since 1900: %d\n",
        timedata.tm_mday, timedata.tm_mon, timedata.tm_year);
      printf("day: %d\nmonth: %d\nyear: %d\n", 
        timedata.tm_mday, timedata.tm_mon + 1, timedata.tm_year + 1900);
    } else {
      puts("Failed");
    }
}
```

Output

```
day: 1
month since January: 0
year since 1900: -1899
day: 1
month: 1
year: 1
```

---

Note: `strptime()` is defined in POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008, also documented in POSIXy systems using man 3 strptime.  It is not in the standard C library.

Comment: (Actually, POSIX.1 functions are in the standard C library, on all POSIXy systems, sometimes requiring preprocessor macros to [expose the features](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html); so, perhaps change the final sentence to *"It's not in the C standard."* instead? Again, apologies for being a pain in the butt.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal "standard C", without attribution, refers to current ISO spec like ISO/IEC 9899:201x.   The "standard C library" I refer to is the functions, macros, variables, etc. as specified in _C11 7 Library_.  So I respectfully  disagree with the suggested change.  Yet leaving your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060653/strptime-reads-years-relative-to-1900ad/45061003?noredirect=1#comment77098165_45061003) does provide detail.

Comment: I suggested that change only because I typically assume (and I suspect most developers assume) the "standard C library" refers to the library or libraries that are automatically included and linked with compiled binaries, in a hosted C environment.